# How to verify behavior based on optional dependencies

Tags: java, junit, classpath

I have code that behaves differently based on the availability of an optional depdency (checked with `Class.forName(...)`).

Is it possible to verify this behavior in junit or is there a library that facilitates this?

I'm hoping there is a better way than bootstrapping a new junit process with a custom classloader.

Alternatively, I could mock a method that returns the classname to check. Then in the test I could use a dummy class or the real class. Still, I would prefer the 'real' test using a missing optional dependency.

Answer (score 1):

By creating custom classloaders, you would have full control over the classpath that is provided to your class/method that needs to check the presence of a certain class to adapt its behaviour.

Check out this code from the [Spark library](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/MutableURLClassLoader.scala) which allows them to mutate the classpath dynamically and even optionally reverse the default order of classpath resolution (normally parent-first). Using such strategy, you could easily mock the classpath using statements like

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() 
ClassLoader mutableClassLoader = new MutableURLClassLoader(urls, classLoader);
// ... manipulate the classpath in mutableClassLoader ...
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(mutableClassLoader);
// everything is set up, you can now call the method you want to test
```

If needed, you can even generate synthetic class on the fly using [JavaCompiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).